# How to open a list of ports with iptables

Tags: networking

I like to open the following ports on ubuntu:

25|80|110|143|443|465|587|993|995

The command `netstat -tulpn | grep -E -w '25|80|110|143|443|465|587|993|995'` Prints the following:

```
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   8489/nginx: master
   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   8489/nginx: master
   tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   8489/nginx: master
   tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   2170/docker-proxy
   tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   2194/docker-proxy
   tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   8489/nginx: master
   tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   2798/docker-proxy
   tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   2675/docker-proxy
   tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   2145/docker-proxy
   tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   3333/docker-proxy
   tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN                                                                                                                                                                   
   2823/docker-proxy
```

How to open theese ports correctly?

Comment: They are open by default. You will have to show us your existing iptables rule set if you have problems. For my part, I can only comment on IPV4 stuff, I have never used IPV6.

Answer (score 0):

UFW (Uncomplicated firewall) is a convenient way to open ports on Ubuntu. By default, UFW should be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 and above.

You can open multiple (`TCP` or `UDP`) ports in this way:

```
ufw allow 25,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995/tcp
```